# Vue Input pass an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, input, frontend

I'm unsure how to approach this problem. I have input and it needs to take a URL and the user can put in as many URLs as they want.

For example:

```
<input 
  type="text"  
  v-model="fields.urls" 
  class="form-control" 
  id="basic-url"
  aria-describedby="basic-addon3">
```

I need to pass an `array` of URLs to the backend like this:

```
 ['firsturl', 'secondurl', ...]
```

Comment: How does the user type URLs? Are they just comma separated values or..? What have you tried to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a better idea to ask for a string of all URLs and convert it into an array.

This will produce an array of URLs out of a comma-separated string.

```
// field.urls = google.com, amazon.com, stackoverflow.com
let urls = fields.urls.split(',').map(x => x.trim())
```